# Как в этой программе можно реализовать ввод с клавиатуры?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as Tk

class Calculator:
    """Main class that constructs the calculator and handles user input and calculations"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Глобальные переменные
        self.operations = {'+': False,
                           '-': False,
                           '*': False,
                           '/': False}
        self.first_number_selected = 0
        self.second_number_selected = 0

        # Расширение элементов для заполнения
        expand_button = Tk.N + Tk.E + Tk.S + Tk.W

        # Установка дисплея
        self.display_label = Tk.Label(parent, text='0', font=('DS-Digital', 27, 'bold italic'),
                                      bg='#c2d899', fg='#3a3e47', height=1, width=20, relief="sunken")
        self.display_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=7, sticky=expand_button)

        # Создание кнопок
        # Кнопки с цифрами
        Tk.Button(parent, height=2, width=12, text='1', bg='#5a5c68', fg="#ffffff", bd='4', font=("Helvetica", 9, "bold"), command=self._number_callback(1)).grid(row=2, column=0)
        Tk.Button(parent, height=2, width=12, text='0', bg='#5a5c68', fg="#ffffff", bd='4', font=("Helvetica", 9, "bold"), command=self._number_callback(0)).grid(row=2, column=1)

        # Операционные кнопки
        for position, operator in enumerate(self.operations.keys()):
            k=0
            Tk.Button(parent, text=operator, height=2, width=12, bg='#bdc1c8', fg="#ffffff", bd='4', font=("Helvetica", 9, "bold"), command=self._operation_callback(operator)).grid(row=3, column=position+k)
        Tk.Button(parent, text='C', height=2, width=25, bg='#bdc1c8', fg="#ffffff", bd='4', font=("Helvetica", 9, "bold"), command=self.reset).grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=expand_button)
        Tk.Button(parent, text='ToDec', height=2, width=15, bg='#bdc1c8', fg="#ffffff", bd='4', font=("Helvetica", 9, "bold"), command=self.bintodec).grid(row=2, column=4, columnspan=1)
        Tk.Button(parent, text='ToBin', height=2, width=15, bg='#bdc1c8', fg="#ffffff", bd='4', font=("Helvetica", 9, "bold"), command=self.dectobin).grid(row=3, column=4, columnspan=1)
        Tk.Button(parent, text='=', height=2, bg='#bdc1c8', fg="#ffffff", bd='4', font=("Helvetica", 9, "bold"), command=self.calculate_result).grid(row=4, columnspan=7, sticky=expand_button)

    def number_pressed(self, button_number):
        """Эта функция вызывается, когда нажимаются 1 или 0"""

        if not any(self.operations.values()):
            if self.first_number_selected == 0:
                self.first_number_selected = button_number
                self.display_label['text'] = str(button_number)
            else:
                self.display_label['text'] += str(button_number)
                self.first_number_selected = int(self.display_label['text'], 2)
        elif self.second_number_selected == 0:
            self.second_number_selected = button_number
            self.display_label['text'] = str(button_number)
        else:
            self.display_label['text'] += str(button_number)
            self.second_number_selected = int(self.display_label['text'], 2)



    def _number_callback(self, number):
        """Вспомогательный метод, который создает функцию обратного вызова
         для каждой из кнопок, обозначающих цифры."""
        return lambda: self.number_pressed(number)

    def operation_selected(self, operation):
        """Эта функция срабатывает при нажатии +, -, * или /.
         Сначала проверяется, введены ли первое и второе число.
         Если это так, рассчитывается результат операции и отображается на дисплее,
             затем устанавливается операция для последнего введенного числа.
         Это позволяет многократно вычислять до нажатия кнопки «=»."""
        if self.second_number_selected and self.first_number_selected:
            self.first_number_selected = self.calculate_result()
            self.display_label['text'] = str(self.first_number_selected)

        self._reset_operations()
        self.operations[operation] = True

    def _operation_callback(self, sign):
        """Вспомогательный метод, который создает функцию обратного вызова
         для каждой из кнопок, которые обозначают операции."""
        return lambda: self.operation_selected(sign)

    def _reset_operations(self):
        """Сброс всех нажатых операций"""
        for operator in self.operations.keys():
            self.operations[operator] = False

    def calculate_result(self):
        """Выполняются вычисления, затем устанавливает переменные для будущих операций с результирующим числом"""
        result = self.first_number_selected
        if self.operations['+']:
            result = self.first_number_selected + self.second_number_selected
        elif self.operations['-']:
            result = self.first_number_selected - self.second_number_selected
        elif self.operations['*']:
            result = self.first_number_selected * self.second_number_selected
        elif self.operations['/']:
            result = round(self.first_number_selected / self.second_number_selected, 3)
            result = int(result, 2) if result.is_integer() else result

        self.first_number_selected = result
        self.second_number_selected = 0  # Resets for next calculation if the clear button is not pressed
        self._reset_operations()
        self.display_label['text'] = bin(result)[2:]

        return result

    def bintodec(self):
        self.display_label['text'] = int(self.calculate_result())

    def dectobin(self):
        self.display_label['text'] = bin(self.calculate_result())[2:]

    def reset(self):
        """Сбросить все переменные в их состояние по умолчанию"""
        self.first_number_selected = 0
        self.second_number_selected = 0
        self._reset_operations()
        self.display_label['text'] = '0'


    @staticmethod
    def run():
        frame = Tk.Tk()
        frame.geometry()
        frame.wm_title('Двоичный калькулятор')
        frame.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        Calculator(frame)
        frame.mainloop()


def main():
    Calculator.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Что именно вы хотите вводить с клавиатуры?

Comment: "1", "0" и операции сложения, вычитания, умножения и деления

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `__init__` добавить привязку к событию нажатия клавиши:

```
parent.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)
```

Добавить метод `key_pressed` (100% правильность не гарантирую, но логика примерно такая):

```
def key_pressed(self, event):
    if event.char in '01':
        self.number_pressed(int(event.char))
    elif event.char in '+-*/':
        self.operation_selected(event.char)
```